# Is there a way to install an app inside Slack that will be available only for the user who has installed it. (App install in personal scope)

Tags: slack, slack-api

Do we have any mechanism inside Slack to install an app for myself. I wanted an app that will help me in performing my tasks. Any other user inside the workspace, if he needs the app should install again.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: To create an app that pushes commands to Slack on your behalf and runs on your device, you can use the Slack Web API. For a bot that listens on your workspace and responds to things like slash commands, you would also need (a workspace admin) to register your app; then you'd program the app to not listen to anyone but you. For direct manipulation of your running Slack client, you'd want a desktop automation tool such as Hammerspoon.

Comment: But I need an app to be available for other users as well. Consider example say in Microsoft Teams, you can add an app into a chat i.e a personal scope and that app can perform tasks for you. But if an another user wants to use that app, he needs to add that app inside his personal scope, without the need of admin intervention. Is there any way that I can expect this behaviour from Slack too.

Comment: In the case of the Web API client, you would give them a copy of your program, and let them use your API key or have them get their own. You could also run your program as a server where you manage the authentication. Obviously, for the desktop automation approach, you just give them a copy of your script. For a bot, I'm not sure what the exact story is, but I've used enough Slack bots to know you don't need an admin to add new users. Worst case, you make your bot available to everyone, and just add new users to your "don't ignore" list as they come.